# Why does document.getElementById not work?

Tags: javascript, ejs

I am working on a website for campground site and this ejs file shows the campground and options for it to be deleted. I wanted to add a feature of giving an alert before the campsite or comment is actually deleted.This code below was working fine before but then i decided to add an alert message whenever the user presses the delete button. So i added the code:

```
    <%var button=document.getElementById("delete");
button.addEventListener("click",function(){
alert("Are you sure?");
})%>
```

to my ejs file:

```
<%- include ("../partials/header.ejs") %>

<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <p class="lead">
                YelpCamp
            </p>
            <div class="list-group">
                <li class="list-group-item active"> Item 1</li>
                <li class="list-group-item"> Item 2</li>
                <li class="list-group-item"> Item 3</li>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-9">
            <div class="thumbnail">
                <img class="img-responsive" src="<%=campground.url%>">
                <div class="caption-full">
                    <h4 class="pull-right">
                     Rs. <%=campground.price%>/Night
                    </h4>
                    <h4>
                        <a href=""><%=campground.name%></a>
                    </h4>
                    <p>
                        <em>Created by <%=campground.author.username%></em>
                    </p>
                    <span class="pull-right">
                        <%if(!currentUser)
                        ;
                    else {
                    if(currentUser.username==campground.author.username){%>
                    <a class="btn btn-xs btn-warning" href="/campgrounds/<%=campground._id%>/edit">Edit </a>
                    <form style="display:inline"action="/campgrounds/<%=campground._id%>?_method=DELETE" method="POST">
                        <button class="btn btn-danger btn-xs" id="delete">Delete</button>
                    </form>
                    <%}}%>
                    </span>
                    <p>
                        <%=campground.description%>
                    </p>
                </div> 
            </div>
            <div class="well">
                
                <span class="pull-right">
                    <a class="btn btn-success" href="/campgrounds/<%=campground._id%>/comments/new"> Add new comment!</a>
                </span>
                <h4>
                    Comments:
                </h4>
                <hr>
                <% campground.comments.forEach(function(comment){%>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                        <strong> <%=comment.author.username%></strong>
                        <span class="pull-right">
                            10 days ago
                        </span>
                        <br>
                        <span class="pull-right">
                        <%if(currentUser && currentUser._id.equals(comment.author.id)){%>
                        <a href="/campgrounds/<%=campground._id%>/comments/<%=comment._id%>/edit" class="btn btn-xs btn-warning">Edit</a>
                        <form style="display:inline"                                                                                     action="/campgrounds/<%=campground._id%>/comments/<%=comment._id%>?_method=DELETE" method="POST">
                        <button class="btn btn-danger btn-xs" id="delete" >Delete</button>
                    </form>
                        <%}%> 
                        </span>
                        <p>
                            <%=comment.text%>
                        </p>
                        <hr>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <%});%>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
 <%var button=document.getElementById("delete");
button.addEventListener("click",function(){
alert("Are you sure?");
})%>
<a href="/campgrounds"> Go back!</a>
<%- include ("../partials/footer.ejs")%>
```

This is just one file from my whole project. But when i run this page it shows the error that document is not defined?

Comment: This is client-side code; you're trying to execute it in the context of ejs parsing the file though. `document` is an in-browser object, it doesn't exist while ejs parses your template.

Comment: So how could i alert the user when it tries to press the delete button?

Comment: Your code is more or less fine (except that you may want to use `confirm()` instead of alert), but you need to insert it in a way that makes expess/ejs send it to the browser instead of executing it.

Answer (score 2):

It's trying to execute `document.getElementById` in your *template*, not in the browser. By the time the browser gets it it's already blown up.

Answer (score 1):

Remember that the template is created/parsed on the server (through `res.render(...)`). To get around this, you could simply include a `<script>` in the template which will be executed in the browser:

```
<!-- rest of the ejs-template -->
<script> 
var button=document.getElementById("delete");
button.addEventListener("click",function(){
   alert("Are you sure?");
});
</script>
```

Comment: Hi thanks now it does not give an error but this does not seem to work. it does not give me any alerts when i press the delete button

Comment: You need to put the script at the end of the template - or wait for the document to load (see https://javascript.info/onload-ondomcontentloaded) and define the button listener inside the `DOMContentLoaded` callback.

Comment: @Nandz Please post a new question for the new problem you encountered.